# Get email address of selected emails sent to me

Tags: thunderbird

How can I see and also copy all email addresses for selected messages? Thunderbird doesn't even has column for that... Why? I can only select myself (recipient)

[image]

Comment: are you talking about the `from` column?

Comment: @jsotola `from` in thunderbird is just a name (without email address), anyway I solved the issue by exporting selected emails in eml format and extracting "from email addresses" using Aid4Mail program